# What is better driver for GeForce Gt 220 M?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, lubuntu

Are three times that I format my notebook, and I play on Nexuiz online.
And I need what is the best driver for target device video GeForce Gt 220M.
I use Lubuntu 64 bit:

```
uname -a
Linux mrk 3.16.0-28-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 12 17:37:40 UTC 2014
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is the image that there are 5 options:

[image]

I have the driver that is checked how in image and with this question, I want to know, which is the better driver for fast "reproduction video"?

Update:
Ok I compile `ubuntu-drivers devices` and the result is:

```
 ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000654sv00001043sd00002039bc03sc00i00
model    : G96M [GeForce GT 220M]
driver   : nvidia-304-updates - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-331-updates - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-331 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
driver   : nvidia-304 - distro non-free
```

Then what is the better because I not understand `distro` or `free` or `non-free`

Comment: @karel Excuse for my ignorance and thx for you suggest.. now you can help for suggest driver?

Comment: If you see on update's question is driver: ´nvidia-304-updates - distro non-free´ @karel

Comment: Open the terminal and run the command: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 && sudo reboot` to install the recommended NVIDIA proprietary graphics driver and reboot the computer to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

You need `bumblebee` and `bbswitch`. You will break your installation if you switch to these nvidia drivers directly. These don't play well with the Optimus card you have.

It is possible to install head from the software updater, but like I said, head over to bumblebee and it will manage a lot for you